# Angular2 Child Route Data

Tags: angular, routes, components

Maybe this question has already been answered somewhere, I could not track down this answer.

I am currently looking for information on how one might pass data from a parent component with a router outlet to a child component that would be routed to within that parent.

I am familiar with `@Input()` and `@Output`, but I am not looking for that.

**Here is what I'd like to do:**

Say I have a parent component with the route `/#/users/:id`

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-cmpt',
    template: `
        <div>
          <h1>User Page</h1>
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    `
})
export class ParentComponent {

    user: IUser;

    constructor(
      private userService: UserService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        userService.getUser(route.snapshot.params['id'])
          .subscribe(data => this.user = data);
    }
}
```

The Parent pulls the user by `:id` from the route params. Now say I have a child component with the route `/#/users/:id/profile`.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'user-profile'
  template: `
    <div>{{ user.username }}</div>
  `
})
export class UserProfile {

    user: IUser;

    constructor() {
      // I don't Want to pull from API here again.
    }
}
```

What I don't want to do is inject `userService` again and have to call getUser` method to re-pull the info from the API.  How can I access the already fetched user object from the parent component?

I am hoping for some cool angular2 way to do this, but as a last resort understand that I may need to create a shared service for this, but that always feels a bit dirty to me for some reason.

Comment: Can you make your `user` in `UserProfile` an `@Input()` and pass the user in with the `user-profile` component\selector? Maybe?

Comment: I don't think so because the component is loaded via the router, so I'm not defining `<user-profile [user]="user"></user-profile>` in any template because its auto loaded into router outlet